# Date textField in Gui , is unable to save in oracle database

Tags: jdbc, oracle10g, prepared-statement, windowbuilder

- Dear all,
- i am unable to save Date in a database (oracle) using GUI text Field...
  *.....
- i created , one JtextField
- i want:
  *1)show date model like(24/3/2014) in jtextField In GUI .....
- but am getting error .. cant convert string to Date type..
- 2) unable to save date in a Oracle DB
- err: it showing null(-)
- please suggest how to code..
- thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest manually converting your string, to a format that Oracle will understand as a date, before you insert it into the database.

That should look like:  2014-03-24